# How to prevent a block element from causing a line break?

Tags: css, google-chrome, line-breaks

I have the following code:

```css
div { width: 200px; margin: 20px }
span { display: block; float: left; margin-left: -20px; background: #f55; width: 1em; height: 1em }
```

```html
<div>Hello world, this is a long paragraph with multiple lines of words, that should only b<span></span>reak at the end of a word. But this doesn't always work, unfortunately.</div>
```

In Firefox, it displays perfectly fine. However, in Chrome, the word "break" is split, with the "b" on a different line than "reak". How can I prevent a line-break from happening here?

Comment: The _actual_ question here should probably rather be, how can I get such a red square centered regarding the overall text height (I’m assuming that is what you actually want to achieve here?), and the answer would be, use `flexbox` (and ideally, a pseudo element instead of the span), instead of trying to place HTML elements _into_ the text at specific positions.

Comment: @CBroe actually, no. I don't want the red box centered; I want it to be on the same row as the word "break". This is obviously a simplified example; in my real application, the content, and the location of the red boxes, are generated dynamically, and when it so happens that the red box is located in the middle of a word at the beginning of a line, this bug appears.

Comment: @Inkbug Can you draw an **illustration** to show what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want the red box centered; I want it to be on the same row as the word "break".

Then try and place your `span` element *after* the word `break` (that will prevent the word itself from breaking, as it currently happens because the span is inserted *inside* the word), and **instead of floating it, position it absolute**.

If you leave the `top` value at the default `auto`, then the span will be positioned at the same “height”, as it would be in normal flow. By setting an explict value for `left` only, you can drag it to the start of that “line”.

```css
div { width: 200px; margin: 20px }
span { position:absolute; left: 0; background: #f55; width: 1em; height: 1em }
```

```html
<div>Hello world, this is a long paragraph with multiple lines of words,
     that should only break<span></span> at the end of a word. But this
     doesn't always work, unfortunately.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This was my fallback plan, but I was hoping for some way to deal with this without moving the spans.